# Save a foreign key, but not the whole object in WCF Data Services

Tags: silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

I'm using Silverlight 4, Entity Framework 4 and WCF Data Services.
Say I have a Playlist object. That Playlist object has properties and a Foreign Key represented by a 0 to 1 navigation property to a Display Object. In the database there is a Display_Id column.

I'm trying to save the playlist and setting the display_id directly, without loading a whole display object from the database (I get the display id from the query string). 
I've tried :

```
playlist.Display = new Display() { Id = 3136 };
// this SetLink throws an exception that the Display is not yet tracked    
context.SetLink(playlist.Display, "Display", playlist);
// or i've tried, but get an error: Entities in 'EDM.Displays' participate in the //'DisplayX' relationship. 0 related 'X' were found. 1 'X' is expected
context.AddToDisplays(playlist.Display);
context.SetLink(playlist, "Display", playlist.Display);
```

Do I need to change my EDM or is there a way to do this on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

first of all You need to attach object to ObjectSet

```
Display d = new Display{ id = 3136 };
context.Displays.Attach(d);
```

it would executed locally without calling database, and then you can work as you need

there is another way: object playlist contains object DysplayReference with property EntityKey if it's null then create it, else just replace key in EntityKeyValues

Comment: I believe that the AddToDisplays method attaches it to the context.

Comment: EF helps those who help themselves ;)